# while run npm run watch command in cli that time this error occur

Tags: vue.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-axios' in 'D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-vue-crud\resources\js' Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?

i am not able to see anything how can i solve this error